# Where is this warning coming from: Warning: `recursive` is deprecated, please use `recurse` instead

Tags: r, warnings

Where is this warning coming from:

```
Warning: `recursive` is deprecated, please use `recurse` instead
```

I've seen it here: https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html#create_package

But also when running: `pkgdown:::build_site_external()`.

Google-fu shows other contexts where this warning shows up.

With me, this warning only started showing up when I updated to R 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it stems from the `fs` package. See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fs/versions/1.3.1) for example.